# Compiler returns error

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

This is my code, the compiler seems to return an error that says, "type UIViewController does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource" every time i try to build. Why does it do that? and what does it mean?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var items:[String] = []
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }

     func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        if var storeditems: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("items") {
            items = []
            for var i = 0; i<storeditems?.count; ++i {
                items.append(storeditems?[i] as NSString)

            }
        }
    }
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {

        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete {
            items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(items, forKey: "items")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you wrote all the `UITableView` related functions inside the `viewDidLoad()` method. In swift we can nest functions, it won't show any error and it'll treat all `UITableViewDataSource` method as your normal instance methods. Hence it's showing that compiler error "**type UIViewController does not conform to protocol UITableViewDataSource**"

Change your code like:

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var items:[String] = []
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
   {
       super.viewDidLoad()
       // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
   {
       return items.count

   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
   {

        var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "cell")
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.orangeColor()
        cell.textLabel?.text = items[indexPath.row]
        return cell
   }

   func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)
   {
        if var storeditems: AnyObject? = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("items")
        {
            items = []
            for var i = 0; i<storeditems?.count; ++i
            {
                items.append(storeditems?[i] as NSString)    
            }
        }
   }

   func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!)
   {
        if editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete
        {
            items.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(items, forKey: "items")
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()

            tableView.reloadData()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help buddy. I have another question now, just out of curiosity i tried pasting the code above the function viewDidLoad, the compiler did not return any error then. Now the question is why is it important to write codes in either viewDidLoad or outside of it or inside didReceiveMemoryWarning? I am quite a beginner at programming hence i want to learn this.

Comment: @VaradJoshi: In swift, you can nest functions (as stated in my answer) means you can write a function inside another function. It's a feature of swift (that's why you didn't get any error). You should start from [here](https://itunes.apple.com/us/book/swift-programming-language/id881256329?mt=11&uo=8&at=11ld4k&uo=8&at=11ld4k).